# Чтение n-ого бита в байте

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte, bit

Подскажите как можно реализовать чтение 7-ого,8-ого бита в 1-ом байте?

Comment: В чём сложность?

Comment: Обычно битовым and с степенью двойки с номером бита, нумерация с ноля. т.е. 7-й  64, а 8-й  128.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Алгоритм:

- Делайте сдвиг числа на указанное количество бит
- Выполняете битовое `и`

Пример:

```
def get_bit(num: int, pos: int) -> bool:
    return num >> pos & 1

# Счет идет с 0, поэтому 8 это проверка 9-го бита
print(get_bit(0b11110000, 8))  # 0

print(get_bit(0b11110000, 7))  # 1
print(get_bit(0b11110000, 6))  # 1

# Перебор всех битов числа
print([get_bit(0b11110000, i) for i in range(8)])
# [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

К чему такие сложности?
Всё намного проще:

```
byte = 128
print(format(byte, "b")[-8])
```

Вывод:

```
1
```

Comment: Тут есть один минус -- нужно добивать нулями слева, иначе можно выход за пределы строки получить: `print(format(8, "b")[-8])  # IndexError: string index out of range`, хотя по хорошему, должно вернуть 0 или тогда самому возвращать исключение специального вида

Comment: Можно просто добавить заведомо старший бит. Например, если мы точно не собираемся выходить за пределы байта то print(format(256+byte, "b")[-8])